# What does Linux do when the /tmp directory is flooded?

Tags: linux, tmp

<strike>From my knowledge of the `/tmp` directory, it is cleared on reboot.</strike>

I'm unsure what happens to the living host whenever the `/tmp` folder is flooded (put to the max storage capacity) - does Linux have some
sort of fail safe to this, or will it, until reboot, leave the files there?

Comment: Your assumption that `/tmp` always gets cleared on reboot is wrong - POSIX recommends "that files and directories located in /tmp be deleted whenever the system is booted" ([source](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s18.html)), but it's not required, some distros don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /tmp directory, it is cleared on reboot

If it's `tmpfs` (valid for some newer distros), then yes. Otherwise it's not generally cleaned up on reboot or shut down. Old files in it could be cleaned up by a cron/systemd timer task.

An addendum by @telcoM: *"On distros using `systemd`, you might find `systemd-tmpfiles` cleaning the temporary files, triggered by `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` and configurable by a `tmpfiles.d` directories under `/usr/lib/` (distribution's standard config), `/etc/` (local customizations) and `/run/` (non-persistent configuration). `RHEL 7` (and newer?) use this mechanism to auto-clean any files that have not been modified in 30 days from `/tmp`."*

> what happens to the living host whenever the /tmp folder is flooded (put to the max storage capacity)

Nothing much, most Linux utilities/services don't actively write to /tmp. If they do, it's solely application dependent.

> does Linux have some sort of fail safe to this, or will it, until reboot, leave the files there?

No failsafe that I'm aware of. It's your responsibility as a user.

Comment: On distros using `systemd`, you might find `systemd-tmpfiles` cleaning the temporary files, triggered by `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` and configurable by a `tmpfiles.d` directories under `/usr/lib/` (distribution's standard config), `/etc/` (local customizations) and `/run/` (non-persistent configuration). RHEL 7 (and newer?) use this mechanism to auto-clean any files that have not been modified in 30 days from `/tmp`, and that caused us a bit of a surprise at work. Fortunately we had backups. A lesson to not leave anything important in `/tmp` for sure.